# Check if Carbon date matches YYYYMMDD HH:MM in PHP

Tags: php, date, php-carbon

I am trying to determine if a string passed into a method matches the format of 'YYYYMMDD HH:MM'. I'm able to convert the string into a `Carbon` date object if that helps for the verification logic. How would I best determine if the format matches my expectations?

Comment: You can use `DateTime::createFromFormat()` and `DateTime::getLastErrors()`. I had written a complete answer but the question was closed before I could hit *Post*.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to convert your input to a UNIX timestamp, then create a new date string using your desired format, and compare the input to that test date string.

```
<?php
$dateFormat = 'Ymd h:i';
$dateInput = '20200827 10:07';

$time = strtotime($dateInput);
$testDate = date($dateFormat, $time);

if($dateInput==$testDate)
{
    echo 'Valid format'.PHP_EOL;
}
else
{
    echo 'Invalid format'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: `DateTime::createFromFormat($dateFormat, $dateInput)->format($dateFormat) === $dateInput` is safer as it will also work with format that `strtotime` cannot parse.